# php + xml wuthout no extensions

Tags: php, xml, php-extension

all!

If my memory serves me right, all xml-related stuff in php is in extensions. Maybe there's a way to work with xml withou any extensions?

thank you in advance!

Comment: can't you just install simple xml? building an xml processing class, wasted time to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML files are normal text files. You can use any file or text related function. But as the others already said: You will be reinventing the wheel again. You can search on the net for other classes that would do it without those extensions. Maybe you can find some. [PHPclasses.org](http://www.phpclasses.org/search.html?words=xml&x=0&y=0&go_search=1) has probably something you are searching for. But as the others said as well, your question is not specific enough.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific? As far as I know all you need for working with XML is libxml (libxml2).

Comment: libxml2 is extension, the question is about possibility of working with xml withou extensions :)